# Create a random binary variable for a subset of observations assigning 1 to a specific proportion of rows

Tags: r, random, tidyverse, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe...

```
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:10, 
  family = c("a","a","b","b","c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
  )
```

Families will only contain 2 members at most (so they're either individuals or pairs).

For individuals (families with only one row, i.e. id = 5:10), I want to create a column called 'random' that randomly assigns 50% of the entries as 1 and the rest as 0. All other rows (those belonging to families with 2 members) should also equal 0.

By the end, the data should look like the following (depending on which 50% of rows are assigned 1)...

```
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:10, 
  family = c("a","a","b","b","c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"),
  random = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
  )
```

I am mostly using Tidyverse and would like to include it within a pipe.

I am currently trying something along the lines of...

```
df %>%
   group_by(family) %>% 
   mutate(random = if(n() == 1) *not sure what goes here* else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can assign 0 if number of rows in a `family` is greater than 1 else select a random value between 0 and 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(family) %>%
  mutate(random = if(n() > 1) 0 else sample(0:1, 1))

#      id family random
#   <int> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1     1 a           0
# 2     2 a           0
# 3     3 b           0
# 4     4 b           0
# 5     5 c           1
# 6     6 d           1
# 7     7 e           0
# 8     8 f           0
# 9     9 g           0
#10    10 h           0
```

---

If we want a fixed number of 1's and 0's for groups with 1 value we can use

```
df %>%
  add_count(family) %>%
   mutate(n = replace(n, n > 1, 0),
          n = replace(n, {inds = which(n == 1);sample(inds, length(inds)/2)}, 0))


# A tibble: 10 x 3
#      id family     n
#   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     1 a          0
# 2     2 a          0
# 3     3 b          0
# 4     4 b          0
# 5     5 c          1
# 6     6 d          0
# 7     7 e          0
# 8     8 f          1
# 9     9 g          1
#10    10 h          0
```

Comment: This is nearly there, but I need exactly 50% 1s and 0s (so 3 of each) for the 6 rows with unique family values (i.e. id == 5:10). This gives me a random number of 1s each time.

Comment: Okay. Updated the answer. Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N > 1) 0 else sample(0:1, 1), family]
```